# set a link to an external web page on which auto redirect should take place

Tags: html, angular, redirect, hyperlink

If the external URL is typed in the browser address bar directly, a redirection to a pdf file happens.
i.e. if you enter https://www.the-external-site.com/information/ and press enter, the page is getting loaded and immediately after that a pdf opens. You can see the url changing to the pdf (i.e. https://www.the-external-site.com/fileadmin/the-information.pdf). Normally, only the URL with the "placeholder" is known to public, because the name and version of the pdf file can change over time.

Now, if I set a Link to this external URL like `<a mat-raised-button color="primary" href="https://www.the-external-site.com/information/" target="_blank"> to the pdf </a>` the first site gets loaded but the redirection to the pdf doesn't happen.

I tried to create a word file and entered the link there and clicked it. The redirection works here.

What am I missing?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the links I provided above are just examples. These Pages do not exist, they are only meant to describe the structure of the problem.

Comment: This is not true in fact. When correctly navigating through android chrome to the path where the redirection appears, the pdf-ressource is loaded.

Comment: I just tested it with my android. It works there too. But that was not even the point.
The point is, that something is wrong with the link to this mechanism.